# Print only the path of the file found

Tags: command-line, find

When I type this command :
find / -name Gson
the terminal prints all the folders it is searching and then somewhere in between I see the path
Can I somehow print just the path of the file found and not all the other details?

Comment: if you want to get rid of all of the error messages you should use ``find / -name *filename* 2> /dev/null``. The ``2> /dev/null`` takes any errors that are produced and sends it to /dev/null, which is a place things go to disappear. Is it the errors that you are bothered by?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! `find` should not print all folders by default. If @Gordster’s advice is not helpful for you, please [edit] your question and add a sample of your `find` output. Don’t forget to apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to pasted terminal text.